# Has the Convoy Effect from Python's GIL been solved since Python 3.2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, gil

I am investigating how Python's GIL works. I'm learning from the slides below, but I have one question.

http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf

This slide describes a new GIL from Python 3.2 and provides an overview. Among them, as a drawback of the new GIL, Convoy Effect that I/O bound threads are not processed efficiently is introduced.

And, as a potential improvement, there is a possibility that this can be solved by giving priority depending on whether thread is I/O bound or CPU bound.

Was such an improvement actually implemented since Python 3.2? Please introduce the contents if it has already been implemented.

Answer (score 4):

Dave's suggested fix, or others, have not been implemented in Python, as of Python 3.10. And this is the [relevant issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue7946), currently closed as `wontfix`, so it feels safe to say that this Convoy Effect problem won't be fixed in the near future either, at least.

My understanding is that it's unclear if this is actually a problem that impacts code in production, and that fixes would touch a risky part of Python to change. Hence the reluctance. If it were shown to be an actual problem experienced in production systems, and not just a theoretical one, I assume the discussion would shift.